# Receive multiple intents on an activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have to send data from two different activities via intents to the same activity. From activity1, the intent is passing data to EnquireActivity, and from activity2 also, the intent is being passed to EnquireActivity. How to receive these intents in the EnquireActivity. Any help would be appreciated.

Activity 1:

```
    Intent i1 = new Intent(this, EnquireActivity.class);
    i1.putExtra("name",et_name.getText().toString());
    i1.putExtra("adults",et_adult.getText().toString());
    i1.putExtra("child",et_child.getText().toString());
    i1.putExtra("email",et_email.getText().toString());
    i1.putExtra("phone",et_phone.getText().toString());
    i1.putExtra("datedept",date1);
    i1.putExtra("datearr",date2);
    i1.putStringArrayListExtra("list1", getChecked);
    startActivity(i1);
```

Activity 2:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, EnquireActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", name);
        intent.putExtra("night", n);
        intent.putExtra("day", d);
        intent.putExtra("dest", dest);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Accept the answer if you don't have any other query.

Answer (score 1):

In EnquireActivity `onCreate()` method

Get the extras from the intent like this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras != null) {
    if(extras.contains("child"){
        // that is the intent if from activity1 and contains additional parameters
        name = extras.getString("name");
        datedept = extras.getString("datedept");
        ...


    }
    else{
        intent.putExtra("name", name);
        night = extras.getString("night");
        day = extras.getString("day");
        dest = extras.getString("dest");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle all the intent in your "onNewIntent()"

```
/**
 * This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in
 * their package, or if a client used the {@link Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP}
 * flag when calling {@link #startActivity}.  In either case, when the
 * activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead
 * of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be
 * called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to
 * re-launch it. 
 *  
 * <p>An activity will always be paused before receiving a new intent, so 
 * you can count on {@link #onResume} being called after this method. 
 * 
 * <p>Note that {@link #getIntent} still returns the original Intent.  You 
 * can use {@link #setIntent} to update it to this new Intent. 
 * 
 * @param intent The new intent that was started for the activity. 
 *  
 * @see #getIntent
 * @see #setIntent 
 * @see #onResume 
 */
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
}
```

Take your code for example, you are sending different intents (different in data extras) to the same activity. So you can check the data extras in the onNewIntent function to tell the sender and take the different operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 approaches:

Approach 1: You can use sharedprefence store data in them and use it in your 3rd activity

Approach 2: Send the intent from 1st activity to 2nd.
            Receive those intents in 2nd.
            Then from 2nd activity send all the previous intents plus the new intents to 3rd activity

Approach 3: Use bundled string

Answer (score 0):

To get the intent from the EnquireActivity Activity try this:

```
Intent in = getIntent();
String tv1= in.getExtras().getString("name");
String tv2= in.getExtras().getString("adults");
String tv3= in.getExtras().getString("child");
String tv4= in.getExtras().getString("phone");
......//Like this
```